# EC2 instance created using terraform with autoscaling group not added to ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, cloudposse

**TL;DR:** Does my EC2 instance need an IAM role to be added to my ECS cluster? If so, how do I set that?

---

I have an EC2 instance created using an autoscaling group. ([ASG definition here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080035/cant-ssh-into-ec2-instance-launched-from-an-autoscale-group/72081740).) I also have an ECS cluster, which is set on the spawned instances via `user_data`. I've confirmed that `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` on the running instance looks correct:

```
ECS_CLUSTER=my_cluster
```

However, the instance never appears in the cluster, so the service task doesn't run. There are tons of questions on SO about this, and I've been through them all. The instances are in a public subnet and have access to the internet. The error in `ecs-agent.log` is:

```
Error getting ECS instance credentials from default chain: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain.
```

So I am guessing that the problem is that [the instance has no IAM role](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598222/1749551) associated with it. But I confess that I am a bit confused about all the various "roles" and "services" involved. Does this look like a problem?

[image]

If that's it, where do I set this? I'm using Cloud Posse modules. [The docs say](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/ecs-alb-service-task/aws/latest#input_service_role_arn) I shouldn't set a `service_role_arn` on a service task if I'm using "awsvpc" as the networking mode, but I am not sure whether I should be using a different mode for this setup (multiple containers running as tasks on a single EC2 instance). Also, there are several other roles I can configure here? The ECS service task looks like this:

```hcl
module "ecs_alb_service_task" {
  source = "cloudposse/ecs-alb-service-task/aws"
  # Cloud Posse recommends pinning every module to a specific version
  version = "0.62.0"

  container_definition_json = jsonencode([for k, def in module.flask_container_def : def.json_map_object])

  name               = "myapp-web"
  security_group_ids = [module.sg.id]
  ecs_cluster_arn    = aws_ecs_cluster.default.arn
  task_exec_role_arn = [aws_iam_role.ec2_task_execution_role.arn]

  launch_type                = "EC2"
  alb_security_group         = module.sg.name
  vpc_id                     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids                 = module.subnets.public_subnet_ids
  network_mode               = "awsvpc"
  desired_count              = 1
  task_memory                = (512 * 3)
  task_cpu                   = 1024
  deployment_controller_type = "ECS"
  enable_all_egress_rule     = false

  health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 10
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200

  ecs_load_balancers = [{
    container_name   = "web"
    container_port   = 80
    elb_name         = null
    target_group_arn = module.alb.default_target_group_arn
  }]
}
```

And here's the policy for the `ec2_task_execution_role`:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_task_execution_role" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:** Here is the rest of the declaration of the task execution role:

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_task_execution_role" {
  name               = "${var.project_name}_ec2_task_execution_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_task_execution_role.json

  tags = {
    Name    = "${var.project_name}_ec2_task_execution_role"
    Project = var.project_name
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2_task_execution_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ec2_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}


# Create a policy for the EC2 role to use Session Manager
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ec2_role_policy" {
  name = "${var.project_name}_ec2_role_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.ec2_task_execution_role.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : [
          "ssm:DescribeParameters",
          "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
          "ssm:GetParameters",
          "ssm:GetParameter"
        ],
        "Resource" : "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

**Update 2:** The EC2 instances are created by the Auto-Scaling Group, [see here for my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080035/cant-ssh-into-ec2-instance-launched-from-an-autoscale-group/72081740). The ECS cluster is just this:

```hcl
# Create the ECS cluster
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "default" {
  name = "${var.project_name}_cluster"
  tags = {
    Name    = "${var.project_name}_cluster"
    Project = var.project_name
  }
}
```

I was expecting there to be something like `instance_role` in the [ec2-autoscaling-group](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/ec2-autoscale-group/aws/latest) module, but there isn't.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Do you have any idea how to do this? I actually see a very similar role created [inside the module](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-ecs-alb-service-task/blob/eb722701d956c9bcac1ff0a91322c69959badacb/main.tf#L223). I'm creating it to give permission to the EC2 tasks to access SSM. (I've updated the question.)

Comment: The task_role_arn is not the place to assign an EC2 instance role. That's going to be the role for the ECS task (the docker container). All the code you have included in your question is related to the ECS service and ECS task, which is something that would only matter much later in the process. You need to show how the ECS cluster and the EC2 instance is created.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I've added more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the EC2 instance profile (IAM instance role) via the `iam_instance_profile_name` setting in the `module "autoscale_group"`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I needed to create a role that used the `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` managed policy and use that role to create an instance profile. Then I set that profile as described in the `autoscale_group`, _et voilà_!